# Как экспортировать строку с переменными через конвейер?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, export, environment-variables

Как экспортировать перменные описывающие реквизиты доступа AWS или, по другому, как экспортировать строку с перменными полученную в результате фильтрации `jq`?

Временное решние

```bsh
tmp_creds="$(mktemp)"

aws sts assume-role \
  --duration-second 1800 \
  --role-arn "$S3_UPLOAD_ROLE_ARN" \
  --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session > "$tmp_creds"

export $(jq -r '.Credentials | \
    "ACCESS_KEY_ID=" + .AccessKeyId, \
    "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=" + .SecretAccessKey, \
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=" + .AccessKeyId, \
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=" + .SecretAccessKey, \
    "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=" + .SessionToken' \
    "$tmp_creds")
```

Пример JSON объекта, возвращаемого `aws sts assume-role`

```json
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA3XFRBF535PLBIFPI4:s3-access-example",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/xaccounts3access/s3-access-example"
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
        "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
        "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
    }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html#examples

Я знаю, что экспортировать строку с переменными довольно тривиально:

```bsh
var_string="var1=1 var2=2 var3=3"
export $var_string
export
```

```
declare -x var1="1"
declare -x var2="2"
declare -x var3="3"
```

Можно ли такое реализовать через конвейер `|` без промежуточной переменной или файла?

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) // постарайтесь, чтобы мы не придумывали, что именно у вас не работает. потому что то, что вы написали в вопросе, отлично работает: `$ export var=blabla; ls | bash -c 'echo $var'`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Хорошо, рассширил вопрос. Хочу сократить код, исключив промежуточную перменную или файл.

Comment: дык, просто подать вывод `aws` на вход `jq`, не?

Comment: и опять нам надо выдумывать, что же именно у вас не получается. потому что то, что вы написали, отлично работает: `$ export var=$(echo '{"var":"blabla"}' | jq -C '."var"'); bash -c 'echo $var'`. напишите, пожалуйста минимальный пример, как и что вы запускаете, что ожидаете получить, и что получаете в результате.